# Are moved labels updated?

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I'm using a multipolygon PostGIS layer in QGIS 3 and created a rule-based labeling. I'd like to know if when a label is moved by `move label and diagram` will it be possible to update the label by changing the entry in the attribute table?

Answer (score 2):

You question is not entirely clear to me, so I cover both options.

**Position, by changing coordinates in attribute table?**

Yes, if:

the label position refers to these coordinate fields in the attribute table.

No, if:

you are using auxilliary storage for coordinates of label positions. This is the standard setting if you use this tool and didnt change it yourself.

**Label, by changing the label value?**

Yes, always. Maybe it is necessary to move the canvas a little so the screen gets updated.